# How do I check if my key is updated in a keyserver after I resend it with new signatures?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, gnupg, key-server

I'm working in a task for class where I need to sign my public key with 3 signatures. After I got them, I need to send my key back to the keyserver with these 3 new signatures.
The thing is that when I search for my key, I just get an output that looks like this:

```
gpg: data source: http://130.206.1.8:11371
(1)     adrian <adristudy@gmail.com>
          3072 bit RSA key A8C9AC79B5643A94, created: 2019-10-27, expires: 2021-10-26
```

Of course, with only that output I can't figure out the signatures within it. And also, I don't want to add the key to my keyring to check the signatures, because in that case, I suppose that the key in my ring will be updated with the "new info", but it's not new, it's actually old.

So how could I get to know the signatures of my key in the keyserver?

> Post data: Don't try anything funny with this key, I'm only using it for my task, and for nothing more